Livewire Not Responding to Broadcasted Events Using Reverb and Laravel
I'm working on a Laravel project that utilizes Livewire for a real-time marketplace feature. I'm broadcasting events via Reverb (a WebSocket server, similar to Pusher) whenever a new listing is created. While the event is successfully broadcasted and received in the browser, my Livewire component does not seem to respond to it.
Key Points:

Event is successfully broadcasted: The event data shows up in the WebSocket network tab, and I can see it being received by the browser in the console logs.
Livewire component doesn’t respond: Despite the event being received, there's no log output or dd trigger in the refreshListings method, suggesting the listener might not be correctly attached.

Technologies:

Laravel (v11.x)
Livewire (v3.x)
Reverb (for WebSocket broadcasting)
Pusher (JavaScript library for WebSocket handling)

Event Structure:
Broadcasted Event (MarketplaceListingCreated)
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Models\MarketplaceListing;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class MarketplaceListingCreated implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, SerializesModels;

    public MarketplaceListing $listing;
    public array $userIds;

    public function __construct(MarketplaceListing $listing, array $userIds)
    {
        $this->listing = $listing;
        $this->userIds = $userIds;
    }

    public function broadcastOn(): array
    {
        return [
            new Channel('marketplace-listings'),
        ];
    }

    public function broadcastAs(): string
    {
        return 'marketplace-listing-created';
    }
}

Livewire Component (MarketplaceListings)
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use App\Models\MarketplaceListing;
use App\Models\Furniture;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class MarketplaceListings extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public $searchTerm = '';
    public $filterType = null;

    public function getListeners(): array
    {
        return [
            "echo:marketplace-listings,marketplace-listing-created" => 'refreshListings',
        ];
    }

    public function filterBy($type): void
    {
        $this->filterType = $type;
        $this->resetPage();
    }

    public function getListingsProperty(): \Illuminate\Contracts\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator
    {
        $query = MarketplaceListing::query();

        if ($this->filterType) {
            $query->where('sale_type', $this->filterType);
        }

        if ($this->searchTerm) {
            $query->whereHas('furniture', function ($q) {
                $q->where('name', 'like', '%' . $this->searchTerm . '%');
            });
        }

        return $query->with(['furniture', 'seller'])->paginate(9);
    }

    public function refreshListings(): void
    {
        Log::info('MarketplaceListingCreated event received by Livewire.');
        $this->resetPage();  // Refresh the listing view to fetch the latest listings
    }

    public function render(): \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|\Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\Foundation\Application
    {
        $items = Furniture::all()->keyBy('id');

        return view('livewire.marketplace-listings', [
            'listings' => $this->listings, // This uses the getListingsProperty() method
            'items' => $items,
        ]);
    }
}

Observations:

The Event is Successfully Broadcasted and Received: The event appears in the WebSocket tab of the browser and is visible in the console logs:

{
   "event": "marketplace-listing-created",
   "channel": "marketplace-listings",
   "data": "{\"listing\":{\"id\":59,...}}"
}

Additionally, in the Reverb debug output, I see the following:
Broadcasting To ............................................................................................................. marketplace-listings
{
    "event": "marketplace-listing-created",
    "data": {
        "listing": {
            "id": 59,
            "user_id": 3,
            "furniture_id": 194,
            "sale_type": "sale",
            ...
        }
    }
}


Listener Attachment Seems Correct: I’ve verified that the Livewire component is subscribing to the channel correctly. The getListeners() method should be attaching the listener as expected.

Correct Use of broadcastAs: The event uses the broadcastAs method, and the listener in Livewire is using this name, so it should match correctly.

Queue Worker is Running: I’ve confirmed that the Laravel queue worker is running properly, and other broadcasted events (such as notifications) are being handled correctly.


Issue:
Despite the correct setup and the event being received by the browser, the Livewire component does not react to the broadcasted event. There is no log output or dd trigger in the refreshListings method, which indicates that the listener might not be responding to the event.
Additional Details:

Manual Trigger Works: I tried manually triggering the event within Livewire (e.g., via a button click), and this successfully triggered the refreshListings method, so the issue appears to be specific to the broadcasted event.
Similar Setup Works: I've used a similar listener setup with private channels in another Livewire component (NotificationBell), and it works fine there.

Debugging Steps Taken:

Reverb Debugging: Verified the event is correctly broadcasted and received in the browser.
Console Logging: Confirmed that the event data shows up in the console but Livewire still doesn’t respond.
Livewire Listeners: Checked that the listeners are correctly set up using the broadcastAs name.

Question:
Why isn’t the Livewire component responding to the broadcasted event even though the event is being successfully received by the browser? Is there any additional configuration or debugging step I should try to ensure the Livewire component correctly handles the event?


Why isn’t the Livewire component responding to the broadcasted event even though the event is being successfully received by the browser?

It may be a namespace issue, try adding a dot prefix to the event in the getListeners() function:
public function getListeners(): array
{
        return [
        "echo:marketplace-listings,.marketplace-listing-created" => 'refreshListings',
    ];
}

as explained here: 
Livewire not responding to Model Broadcast Events
#4831 
